# html button specify selected

Tags: html

For the HTML  element, how do I specify the button as "selected" for the `onclick` to happen when the users clicks the enter key?

I have a page with one button and that button isn't selected when the page is shown. I want the user to be able to click enter without clicking the button.

```
<button href="#" onclick="create_linkcard();" class="page_button"> <img src="Add.png" />Add</button>
```

Comment: whats the button ie input type=button, or submit or button?

Comment: @david If the button is inside the `<form>`, the type of button is "submit" (as default) otherwise, the default type is "button".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the `enter` keypress with key codes.

```
document.onkeypress = keyPress;

function keyPress(e){
var x = e || window.event;
var key = (x.keyCode || x.which);
if(key == 13 || key == 3){
     create_linkcard();
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of the `create_linkcard();` I put the button focus code `$('#buttonid').focus();` and this works.

Answer (score 0):

If using JavaScript is an option, you could do this:

```
<input type="submit" id="myButton"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("myButton").focus();
</script>
```

It will "select" the button `myButton`.

**Make sure you place the `<script>` after the button element.**

Comment: Focus is the right method for selecting a button.  It's more convenient to use the jquery method `$('#buttonid').focus()`. The only problem is that the focus is removed if I type in the input text box.  I am looking for a way to make the button the default selection when the enter key is pressed.

Comment: Both must be inside the same `<form>` and the button must be `type='submit'`, other than that, it should work...

Comment: OK.  This is what works: calling the `$('#buttonid').focus()` in the keypress event for the inputbox.

Answer (score 0):

You could also place the the JavaScript on the **onLoad** event of the **body** tag, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body onload="document.getElementById('pageButton').focus();">
        <button id="pageButton" href="#" onclick="create_linkcard();" class="page_button"> <img src="Add.png" />Add</button>
    </body>
</html>
```