# Making Enter key on an HTML form submit instead of activating button

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have an HTML form with a single `submit` input, but also various `button` elements. When the user presses the 'enter' key, I'd expect it to actually submit the form, but instead (within Chrome 15 at least) I'm finding that it's triggering the first `button` (since that occurs earlier in the HTML than the `submit` input, I guess).

I know that in general you can't force browsers to favour a particular `submit` input, but I really thought they would favour `submit` inputs over `button` elements. Is there a small tweak I can make to the HTML to make this work, or am I going to have to embrace some kind of Javascript approach?

Here's a rough mockup of the HTML:

```
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="field1"/>
    <button onclick="return myFunc1()">Button 1</button>
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/925387/1031900

Comment: @OfirFarchy I guess what I thought made this question different was that there's only ONE submit, the others are all buttons.

Comment: Well if you don't object to using JS and jQuery check my & david's answers

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript to choose your default submit button or input. You just need to mark it up with `type="submit"`, and the other buttons mark them with `type="button"`. In your example:

```
<button type="button" onclick="return myFunc1()">Button 1</button>
<input type="submit" name="go" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work as expected in some browsers. I just ran into this issue today thinking the type="submit" would make it the default, however it does not in Chrome or Safari.

Comment: It works for me in Chrome and Safari. It must be something else.

Comment: Setting the type="button" on the extra buttons AND setting type="submit" is what makes the difference.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work if you don't set `type="button"` is because by default, button elements are `type="submit"`. So the premise in the question that there was only a single submit button was actually incorrect.

Answer (score 31):

You can use jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("form input").keypress(function (e) {
        if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {
            $('button[type=submit] .default').click();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer: Scroll down for a very simple HTML-only solution.

Comment: The HTML solution is the correct answer. A browser handles by default

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but you don't need to use this 'heavy equipment' to solve this problem. Use the HTML only solution (@Jesús Carrera's answer), the browser handles this now.

Comment: The nice thing about this approach -- although yes, it does require jQuery/JavaScript -- is that it will work even if you need to have multiple submit buttons in your form.  The specific selector in this example should not have the space after the `button[type=submit]` however, assuming that you have tagged your default submit button with the `default` css class.

Answer (score 5):

Try this, if enter key was pressed you can capture it like this for example, I developed an answer the other day [html button specify selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281400/html-button-specify-selected/8281520#8281520), see if this helps.

Specify the forms name as for example `yourFormName` then you should be able to submit the form without having focus on the form.

```
document.onkeypress = keyPress;

function keyPress(e){
  var x = e || window.event;
  var key = (x.keyCode || x.which);
  if(key == 13 || key == 3){
   //  myFunc1();
   document.yourFormName.submit();
  }
}
```

Comment: if form have more submit buttons this will help :
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="ok"/>
document.getElementById("submit").click();

Comment: This is an obtuse way to get around default behavior in HTML. See [above answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16462846/1327983) for why.

Answer (score 4):

I just hit a problem with this. Mine was a fall off from changing the `input` to a `button` and I'd had a badly written `/>` tag terminator:

So I had:

```
<button name="submit_login" type="submit" class="login" />Login</button>
```

And have just amended it to:

```
<button name="submit_login" type="submit" class="login">Login</button>
```

Now works like a charm, always the annoying small things... HTH

Answer (score 4):

```
$("form#submit input").on('keypress',function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.which === 13) {
    $('button.submit').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Given there is only one (or with this solution potentially not even one) submit button, here is jQuery based solution that will work for multiple forms on the same page...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var makeAllFormSubmitOnEnter = function () {
            $('form input, form select').live('keypress', function (e) {
                if (e.which && e.which == 13) {
                    $(this).parents('form').submit();
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        };

        makeAllFormSubmitOnEnter();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just gave this a whirl in both Chrome and Firefox and IE10.

As mentioned above - make sure that you have marked up with type = "button", "reset", "submit" etc to ensure that it correctly cascades and chooses the correct button.

Perhaps also setting all of them to have the same form (ie all  as that worked for me)