# Form will not submit when "enter" button pressed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I've got a form that renders when the user opts to create a new account.  Inside app/views/accounts/new.js.erb, I've got some JS that renders the form.

```
$("#freeze_container").find('table > tbody > tr:first').after("<%= j(render(partial: "accounts/form", locals: { account: @new_account }))%>")
```

And this is what that partial looks like:

```
<tr class='new-account'>
  <%= form_for(account, :remote => true, class: "account-form") do |f| %>
    <td>
      <span class="category">
        <%= f.select :category, Account::CATEGORIES %>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="institution">
        <%= f.text_field :institution %>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="name">
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </span>
    </td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

This renders correctly, however, when I enter in values to the form fields and press <kbd>enter</kbd>, nothing happens.  When I look at the logs, it looks like I've taken no action.  What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please Post your accounts_controller.rb

Answer (score 2):

In order for the enter key to work, you need to have an `input` with `type=submit`.

You could add a simple `submit` button to your code and make it hidden with CSS, or, a better option that would be cleaner and work with all browsers, you could use JavaScript and listen on the form for the enter key being pressed.  See [this SO accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294465/making-enter-key-on-an-html-form-submit-instead-of-activating-button) for example jQuery that would do just this.